# Duda en el diseño de estas consultas en SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle-11g

Estoy leyéndome un libro de bases de datos para ampliar mis conocimientos sobre el tema. Al final de cada capítulo vienen ejercicios pero muchos no están resueltos. He encontrado este que me parece interesante y querría saber si estoy planteándolo bien o no. 
Para poneros en situación os resumo un poco:

Se dispone de estas tablas:

```
CLIENTES (

id_cliente  VARCHAR2(15),
DNI         VARCHAR2(9),
nombre      VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
apellido    VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
e-mail      VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
nº movil    NUMBER(12),
fecha nac   DATE,
CONSTRAINT PK_CLIENTES PRIMARY KEY (id_cliente)

);

CONTRATOS (

contractId    VARCHAR2(10),  
id_cliente    VARCHAR2(15),  
startdate     DATE NOT NULL,
enddate       DATE, 
contract_type VARCHAR2(50),
address       VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
town          VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
ZIPcode       VARCHAR2(8) NOT NULL,
country       VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT    PK_contracts PRIMARY KEY (contractId),
CONSTRAINT    FK_contracts1 FOREIGN KEY (clientId) REFERENCES CLIENTES
);
```

La consulta que se pide es: *Obtenga la relación en orden alfabetico de aquellos clientes que tengan un contrato en vigor en el dia de la consulta, asi como su periodo de contrato.*

**¿Qué he hecho yo?**
Creo que la forma de hacer esto es juntar ambas tablas por la columna id_cliente, que es común a ambas, y luego filtrar aquellas tuplas que tengan un contrato en vigor. Para ello creo que se debería poner la condicion de:

```
enddate - sysdate > 0
```

Lo del periodo de contrato diría que es con:

```
enddate - startdate
```

**¿Qué dudas tengo?**

Lo de orden alfabético he mirado que se hace aplicando un ORDER BY nombre_del_campo ¿es así?

Para juntar ambas tablas para luego ir seleccionando las cosas que me interesen es mejor un JOIN, un FULL JOIN... ¿o que?

¿Cómo se consigue que en la tabla, en una columna adicional, salga el periodo de contrato de cada tupla, haciendo lo de enddate - startdate?

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes razón:

***Lo de orden alfabético he mirado que se hace aplicando un ORDER BY nombre_del_campo ¿es así?***

```
select * from clientes order by apellido asc  --orden ascendente A-Z
select * from clientes order by apellido      --orden ascendente A-Z
select * from clientes order by apellido desc --orden descendente Z-A
```

También puedes hacer algo como esto:

```
select * from clientes order by apellido,nombre   --por dos campos
select * from clientes order by nombre,apellido   --por dos campos, primero el nombre
select * from clientes order by (nombre + ' ' + apellido) --por los dos campos pero unidos como si fuera uno solo
```

***Para juntar ambas tablas para luego ir seleccionando las cosas que me interesen es mejor un JOIN, un FULL JOIN... ¿o que?***

Con el `inner join` esta bien, asi te aseguras que exista información en ambas tablas.

***¿Cómo se consigue que en la tabla, en una columna adicional, salga el periodo de contrato de cada tupla, haciendo lo de enddate - startdate?***

Para agregar la columna adicional y en este caso hablas de dos fechas sería algo así:

```
select fecha1, fecha2, (fecha1 - fecha2) as CampoNuevo from tabla
```

Cabe mencionar que las fechas en SQL Server, no estoy segura en Oracle como se haga, existen funciones en SQL Server para realizar operaciones con fechas:

```
select getdate() --Obtiene la fecha actual
select dateadd(d,-10, getdate())  --Resta 10 días a la fecha actual
select dateadd(d,10, getdate())   --Suma 10 días a la fecha actual
-- etc...
```